# Determine if time is before or after specific time

Tags: excel, datetime

I have an Excel sheet with two date-time columns: Start Date and End Date. I need to calculate overtime by determining how many hours and minutes were worked before 08:00 and after 16:30.

Examples:

```
   COLUMN A             COLUMN B
1  2017/01/04 16:00     2017/01/04 18:00
2  2017/01/05 18:00     2017/01/05 21:00
3  2017/01/08 08:00     2017/01/08 17:00
4  2017/01/09 07:00     2017/01/09 09:00
```

I know the calculation for duration between times (=TEXT(B1-A1,"h:mm")), but I'm struggling to determine if a date-time is before 08:00 or after 16:30.

I've played around with TIMEVALUE("8:00:00"), TIMEVALUE("8:00:00 AM") and TIME(8,00,00) in my calculation, but the it did not work,
 e.g. =IF(A1<=TIMEVALUE("8:00:00 AM"),"Yes","No") returns "No" even for A4 (2017/01/09 07:00)

I'm struggling with the calculation and the logic on this one. So far i'm using,

```
=IF(MOD(F2,1)<8/24,8/24-MOD(F2,1),0)+IF(MOD(G2,1)>16.5/24,MO‌​D(G2,1)-16.5/24,0)
```

Comment: So far i'm using =IF(MOD(F2,1)<8/24,8/24-MOD(F2,1),0)+IF(MOD(G2,1)>16.5/24,MOD(G2,1)-16.5/24,0), but it does not solve the problem 100%. If an event is from 06:00 - 07:00, it returns 2:00 but it should actually only be 1:00 (it currently checks the start time (06:00) against the start of the work-day (08:00) and does not take into account that the event ended at 07:00.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick with treating time as time; only treat time as text when you have bad data (time as text is bad data) and then only enough to get it to be time as time.

To get the number of hours and minutes before 08:00 AM,

```
=MAX(0, TIME(8, 0, 0)-TIMEVALUE(TEXT(A2, "hh:mm;0;@")))
```

To get the number of hours and minutes after 16:30 AM,

```
=MAX(0, TIMEVALUE(TEXT(B2, "hh:mm;0;@"))-TIME(16, 30, 0))
```

In the following image you can see that I have left one group as true time and the forced the following group to be time as text¹. Both return correct results.

[image]

---

¹ <sub>Unless specifically formatted otherwise, numbers and dates/times are right-aligned in a cell; text is left-aligned.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`=IF(TIMEVALUE(A1)<=TIMEVALUE("8:00:00 AM"),"Yes","No")`

Comment: Any since 2007: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TIMEVALUE-function-0b615c12-33d8-4431-bf3d-f3eb6d186645.

Comment: Excel 2013 is listed in that link, so it should work.

Comment: `TIMEVALUE(TEXT(A1, "hh:mm;0;@"))` works with time-as-text and time as actual time.